# Lauterbach TRACE32 debugger trace content of a register

Tags: debugging, embedded, trace, lauterbach

I'm working with ARM Cortex CM4 core. I'm using TRACE32 Lauterbach with an off-chip trace.

How can I log the content of the SP register using TRACE32?

Comment: What does the documentation tell you? Why does it not help you?

Comment: Just in case you are trying to track down a stack overflow or such, it might be more useful to place a write breakpoint somewhere the program shouldn't be writing, then view the trace buffer from there.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that tracing of core registers is not supported by the Arm ETM nor the DWT/ITM of Cortex-M. So tracing core registers of a Cortex core is not working with any debugger including TRACE32.